# How to disable vertical scrolbar in DataTable?

Tags: jquery, datatable

I did googling and read the Datatable documentation but could not able to disable the auto vertical scrolbar in DataTable. please let me know how to disable it?

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
       "searching": true,
       "paging":   true,
       "ordering": true,
       "info":     true,


       "language": {
          "url": url,
          "searchPlaceholder": " ... "

      }
```

[image: datatable screenshot]

Comment: I'm not familiar with this `DataTable` function, but if you never want scrolling under any circumstances, you could try adding CSS like `#myTable { overflow: hidden; }`.

Comment: Thank you Kshetline, I have added  `.dataTables_wrapper { overflow: hidden !important; }` and it works now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the scroll `y` to `false`.

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
       scrollY:        false,
       scrollX:        false,
       "searching": true,
       "paging":   true,
       "ordering": true,
       "info":     true,


       "language": {
          "url": url,
          "searchPlaceholder": " ... "

      }
```

Try it with `overflow:hidden` in CSS.

Comment: 'scrollY:        false,
scrollX:        false,'

Comment: I changed my answer and added `overflow:hidden`, please try it now

Comment: "scrollY: false, scrollX:false" worked for me. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
.dataTables_scrollBody {
    overflow-y: hidden!important;
 }
```